# Python append a string with if/else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, append

I want to create list of result string based on `if`-`else` result, but currently only a 1-value string can be seen when running the loop.

Example:

```
for ips in npat:
    ipnet = ips.strip()
    print ("Processing ..... ", ipnet)
    fgen = "grep " +ipnet+ " /mnt/hgfs/IRR/fgen.txt"
    f2pat = re.findall(ipnet,fgen)
    print ("\nCommand: ",fgen)
    os.system(fgen)
    print ("\n NEW NPATH: ",f2pat)

    flist = []
    if ipnet in f2pat:
        flist.append("Grep Found")
        print ("Result ", flist)
    else:
        flist.append("Grep NotFound")
        print ("Result: ",flist)
```

`flist -> ['Grep Found']`...Only 1 value is in the list in spite of ther should be multiple values. May I know your ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried moving `flist = []` outside / above your `for ips in npat` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems that `flist = []` gets reintiallized in the loop. Move that variable alone above your `for loop`. Hence the code becomes :

```
flist = []
for ips in npat:
    ipnet = ips.strip()
    print ("Processing ..... ", ipnet)
    fgen = "grep " +ipnet+ " /mnt/hgfs/IRR/fgen.txt"
    f2pat = re.findall(ipnet,fgen)
    print ("\nCommand: ",fgen)
    os.system(fgen)
    print ("\n NEW NPATH: ",f2pat)


    if ipnet in f2pat:
        flist.append("Grep Found")
        print ("Result ", flist)
    else:
        flist.append("Grep NotFound")
        print ("Result: ",flist)
```

Credits to  jedwards [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736937/jedwards)